# How to get ifOperStatus from the SNMP MIB?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I was trying to get `ifOperStatus` with `snmpget`, but I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674354/snmp-ifadminstatus-vs-ifoperstatus) that he does it like this

```
snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 1 192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8
```

So I tried that but I get no result

[image]

But the SNMP agent is working.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how can I access ifOperStatus?

Comment: Columns should be queried via a WALK operation, or GET-BULK. GET in most cases are for scalar objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your snmpwalk is the NET-SNMP version, then

> snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 1 192.168.1.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8

should work (notice the extra dot in front of the OID).
That makes it an absolute OID, rather than relative.